# Declare Custom Attribute that create a new object

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm not sure what i am trying to do is actually possible.

I want to create a new Custom Attribute where by when the attribute is declared the user creates a new object.

I'm looking at Lucene.Net and i want to add a custom attribute to my class property, so i can determine multiple parameters.

Here is my Custom Attribute, It takes in a Lucene.Net Field object :-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class PropertyAnalysed : Attribute
    {
        public Field Field;

        public PropertyAnalysed(Field field)
        {
            this.Field = field;
        }
    }
```

When I declare the custom attribute on property, I want to do the following :-

```
 [LuceneIndex("SampleIndex")]
    public class SampleClass
    {
        [LuceneProperty]
        [PropertyAnalysed(new Field("","",Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

However, i get the following error :-

> "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
>   type"

Can anyone help on what i can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to take several separate parameters, and create the `Field` instance based on those parameters. You can only configure attributes with compile-time constants, and `new Field(...)` isn't a compile-time constant.

You may not need *all* the parameters anyway - for example, `Field.Index.ANALYZED` sounds like it will be pointless in a `PropertyAnalysed` attribute, as surely *all* fields would have that...

Comment: Thanks, that makes alot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, you can only use compile-time constants - which is to say, only primitives you can declare without use of the new keyword. Since Attributes are class-level, they can't be passed anything which requires a new statement.

Attribute constructors, similarly, won't let you declare a parameter which would be invalid to pass. Attributes also can't be generic - hence the explicit mention of typeof(...) statements being allowed.

Your best bet is to have some way of parsing a Field from a given string, and passing a string into your attribute. If that's not an option, you could also specify a type and string which represent the class and static member you want looked up, and use [reflection to find that property by name.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)